# Usability studies about Unity-type interfaces

Tags: gui-design

I've just installed (upgraded) Ubuntu 11.04. For those of you not familiar with Ubuntu, 11 is the year and 04 is the month. Ubuntu has a six month release cycle, so the next version is around the corner (11.10).

The new version is slick, but I was a bit... confused. On startup, instead of having the system menu at the top of the screen as used to be the case, there is a navigation bar at the left of the screen. This is the [Unity interface](http://unity.ubuntu.com/about/).

[image: Ubuntu 11.04]

In the unity bar (however it's called), there are some applications I frequently use, some I hardly ever use and no system tools or accessories, or any of the visual indicators we're used to.

After some fooling around, it's not so bad, but my feeling is that for new users, the interface offers no indicators about what's really possible, so the learning curve will be steep.

This is the graphical user interface that's closest to the command line I've seen in a while.

So now I come to the question: Are there any usability studies out there testing this type of interface that offer hardly any visual clues? What are their conclusions?

Comment: suggestion: try modifying the question so it's less of a rant and more of a question. Also, what do you mean by "testing this type of interface"?

Comment: @Christofian: Nah, I like to rant sometimes. A serious user test. How do users find things they need to do or change. For instance, I had a hard time configuring the mike because I couldn't find the right configuration tool.

Comment: And consider that I'm an experienced user with more than two years of Ubuntu under my belt (apart from ms-dos, unix and about every windows version since 3.1)

Comment: let me be more specific: I don't get what you mean by "this type of interface". What feature(s) of the user interface are you talking about here?

Comment: @Christofian: Sorry, the left navigation bar with the icons and the invisible system menu. Have you seen the Unity interface?

Comment: OK. Just a suggestion: edit your question so that's more clear.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1506/discussion-between-gui-junkie-and-christofian)

Comment: What confuses me about the question is that there *are* visual clues. The buttons on the sidebar look like buttons. In fact, they are the only things that look clickable on the screen. It may be that this is just different from what you're used to, and more minimal from the sounds of it. I'm curious how it holds up over time.

Comment: @ToddSieling: Let me put it another way, apart from the fact that, if you don't know the icons, you're going to be lost for a while, how would you start Bluetooth, or start K-Stars, or any other application that's not on that sidebar?

Comment: @GUIJunkie So I guess the question is more about how discoverable the applications and other features are. It might be a good way to orient the question, towards something like 'how should an OS make features discoverable' or something along that line?

Comment: @ToddSieling: Exactly. Vitaly's link is an interesting read.

Comment: @GUIJunkie Indeed, some problems but far from a total disaster. It seems most people got to the most common apps, with a few bumps along other tests. Any conclusions from the original question?

Comment: @ToddSieling: Using Unity, I've seen some things that I like, but... having the menu of any window (even windows that are not maximized) hidden at the top of the screen is just wrong (IMO). The conclusion of the test seems to be that there are some serious bumps. Are you a user?

Comment: @GUIJunkie Nope, quite happy on OSX.

Comment: @GUIJunkie BTW, if you're interested in a one-person case study - for me Unity was my first experience with Linux ever, and I'm now gradually switching to it from Win7. So I can't compare it to previous versions, but overall I like it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usability studies have been done by Canonical on the Unity itself, you can read [a summary on the Ubuntu mailing list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-April/032988.html).

Another test here:
http://design.canonical.com/2010/11/usability-testing-of-unity/